# Deliver result from single service to multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, intentservice

I have `ViewPager` in my Activity which contains few fragment for each page.Now as soon as fragment is loaded I am calling a service who's job is to fetch data from webservices and deliver the result to particular fragment with `ResultReceiver` class. To be more clear:

```
FragmentA----->calls FetchDataService()

FragmentB----->calls FetchDataService()
```

Now the `FetchDataService` does not deliver the result to proper fragment, instead I'm receiving the result all at `FragmentB` because it calls `FetchDataService` at last. What is the best way to do it to get the correct result in each fragment.

Comment: Use the local broadcast receiver in fragments, may be it works..

Comment: How often does the FetchDataService need to fetch the data - in other words does the data at the web service end change regularly? Also do FragmentA, FragmentB etc ask the FetchDataService to fetch the same data or does each Fragment want different data?

Comment: Each fragment wants different data, data is fetch once and stored in SQLite database. If the data at webservice end changes it again fetches fresh content  @Squonk

Comment: Would it make more sense for the `Activity` to fetch all of the required data and store it in the SQLite database and then each `Fragment` can simply do their own local DB queries to get the data they need?

Comment: True, but I have multiple request to fetch data from webservices. How to fetch all data at once?? do you know a way to do it ? @Squonk

Comment: I was thinking the `Activity` would just make each of the requests the `Fragments` would normally do one after another but that might not fit your model. I have an app which pulls 10-15MB of zipped files (about 12-14 files). It does it every 24 hours and updates a local DB with multiple tables. Each of my `Fragments` then handle their own SQL queries when they need to. That's all I was thinking if it might work for your app.

Answer (score 2):

Don't let the Fragments poll for data, let them listen to broadcasts.
The FetchDataService would have to send a broadcast with the data when it has received it from the server. Each fragment can than register a broadcastReceiver with correct intentFilter to listen to the broadcasts of the FetchDataService.

```
// Example function to send data with a broadcast
sendData(Context context, Data data) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("fetchedData");
    intent.putExtra("data", data);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}

// Register your reciever to listen to the correct actions (in this case "fetchedData")
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("fetchedData") // use same string here as in sender
context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

// You can create multiple receivers (one for each fragment for example)
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (action.equals("fetchedData")) {
            Data data = (Data)intent.getSerializableExtra("data");
            // Do something with data
        }
    }
}
```

I would make constants from the Strings "fetchedData" and "data" to prevent typos.